# Why is this factory returning undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I would like assistance in figuring out why this service I have created is returning undefined when I print it to console.

**module.js**

```
'use strict';
var Search = angular.module('SearchApp',["ngCookies","ngRoute"]);

Search.run(function ($http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
});

Search.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller:'searchCtrl',
            resolve: {
                dota_items: function (InventoryService){
                    return InventoryService.get('dota');
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
});
```

This is the module file where I have declared a route.

**servcie.js**

```
Search.factory('InventoryService', function ($http, $q) {
    var api_url = "/api/inventory/";
    return {
        get: function (inventory) {
            var inv_url = api_url + inventory + '/';
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: inv_url}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config){
                    defer.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data,status, headers, config){
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell the syntax is correct for my service however I may have missed something.

**controller.js**

```
Search.controller('searchCtrl',['$scope', function($scope, dota_items){

    console.log(dota_items);
    $scope.selected = 'have';

    $scope.setSection = function(section){
        $scope.selected = section;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function(section){
        return $scope.selected == section;
    };

}]);
```

Here is the issue, In the console, the variable is always undefined. I have attempted to check if my service is even being called by printing to console however nothing is logged. I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the `'searchCtrl'` controller with the [inlined array dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) syntax

```
['$scope', function($scope, dota_items) { }]
```

angular ignores the actual argument names in the function in favor of what you've specified in the array. Consider adding `dota_items` to the array before the `function`.

```
Search.controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope','dota_items',function($scope, dota_items) {
  // your code
}]);
```

---

You can also remove the array entirely and use angular's implicit dependencies feature like so:

```
Search.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, dota_items) {
  // your code
});
```

but it should be noted that this approach only works if you're not minifying or obfuscating your code.

Comment: Hi, I have tried both the solutions posted above and now i receive this error. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0/$injector/unpr?p0=dota_itemsProvider%20%3C-%20dota_items. This was the initial error I was receiving before I made the change I did to get undefined. I am not sure what the issue is, as far as i can tell ive included what I need to.

Comment: I don't know either at this point, unless you've got a stray `ng-controller` directive in your markup somewhere that's directly referencing `'searchCtrl'` (because, when I had this problem, that was my mistake) ... if not that, I guess just update your question and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: hmmm, just checked my html file and I've only referenced ng-controller once as well as the app once. I already had a question pertaining to this problem up, so I wont change this one since it will probably be useful to someone new like myself. Thanks

Comment: If you're using `ngRoute`, why do you have `ng-controller` at all? shouldn't you have `ng-view` instead?

Comment: for the moment I am not doing any template work. I just want to try and get the service to return my results. As a result I just put ng-controller there for the moment. Would this be related to the problem at hand? I took the assumption that the controller would work exactly the same regardless.

Comment: Actually, I think that's likely your problem. `ng-controller` will try to instantiate the `'searchCtrl'` itself, independent of whatever you've defined in your route providers. Remove the `ng-controller` directive and put `ng-view` on the same tag, and the `searchCtrl` will be instantiated by ngRoute instead, which knows how to resolve `dota_items`.